# Capturing group with findall?

Tags: python, regex

How can I access captured groups if I do `findall(r'regex(with)capturing.goes.here')` ?
I know I can do it through `finditer`, but I don't want to iterate.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

`findall` just returns the captured groups:

```
>>> re.findall('abc(de)fg(123)', 'abcdefg123 and again abcdefg123')
[('de', '123'), ('de', '123')]
```

Relevant doc excerpt:

> Return all non-overlapping matches of
>   pattern in string, as a list of
>   strings. The string is scanned
>   left-to-right, and matches are
>   returned in the order found. If one or
>   more groups are present in the
>   pattern, return a list of groups; this
>   will be a list of tuples if the
>   pattern has more than one group. Empty
>   matches are included in the result
>   unless they touch the beginning of
>   another match.

Comment: Worth noting is that `re.finditer()` also returns outer non-capturing groups, not just capturing groups like `re.findall()`. Things can get messy very quickly with nested groups, capturing or not. For complex expressions, I recommend using named capturing groups with `re.finditer()`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11104110

Answer (score 46):

Use groups freely. The matches will be returned as a list of group-tuples:

```
>>> re.findall('(1(23))45', '12345')
[('123', '23')]
```

If you want the full match to be included, just enclose the entire regex in a group:

```
>>> re.findall('(1(23)45)', '12345')
[('12345', '23')]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot saved my day with the second piece of information

Answer (score 3):

```
import re
string = 'Perotto, Pier Giorgio'
names = re.findall(r'''
                 (?P<first>[-\w ]+),\s #first name
                 (?P<last> [-\w ]+) #last name
                 ''',string, re.X|re.M)

print(names)
```

returns

```
[('Perotto', 'Pier Giorgio')]
```

`re.M` would make sense if your string is multiline. Also you need `VERBOSE` (equal to `re.X`) mode in the regex I've written because it is using `'''`

Answer (score 0):

Several ways are possible:

```
>>> import re
>>> r = re.compile(r"'(\d+)'")
>>> result = r.findall("'1', '2', '345'")
>>> result
['1', '2', '345']
>>> result[0]
'1'
>>> for item in result:
...     print(item)
...
1
2
345
>>>
```

Comment: I think he's asking about inner-regex groups as in '(group1)..(group2)'

Comment: @bluepnume: Maybe, but his question isn't all that clear. His example only has one capturing group.