# re.findall which returns a dict of named capturing groups?

Tags: python, regex

Inspired by a now-deleted question; given a regex with named groups, is there a method like `findall` which returns a list of `dict` with the named capturing groups instead of a list of `tuple`?

Given:

```
>>> import re
>>> text = "bob sue jon richard harry"
>>> pat = re.compile('(?P<name>[a-z]+)\s+(?P<name2>[a-z]+)')
>>> pat.findall(text)
[('bob', 'sue'), ('jon', 'richard')]
```

Should instead give:

```
[{'name': 'bob', 'name2': 'sue'}, {'name': 'jon', 'name2': 'richard'}]
```

Answer (score 161, accepted):

Using [`Pattern.finditer()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.finditer) then [`Match.groupdict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.groupdict):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "bob sue jon richard harry"
>>> r = re.compile('(?P<name>[a-z]+)\s+(?P<name2>[a-z]+)')
>>> [m.groupdict() for m in r.finditer(s)]
[{'name2': 'sue', 'name': 'bob'}, {'name2': 'richard', 'name': 'jon'}]
```

Comment: This is a much better solution than my version, which focused on using `findall` from the get-go.

Answer (score 16):

you could switch to finditer

```
>>> import re
>>> text = "bob sue jon richard harry"
>>> pat = re.compile('(?P<name>[a-z]+)\s+(?P<name2>[a-z]+)')
>>> for m in pat.finditer(text):
...     print m.groupdict()
... 
{'name2': 'sue', 'name': 'bob'}
{'name2': 'richard', 'name': 'jon'}
```

Answer (score 9):

If you are using match :

```
r = re.match('(?P<name>[a-z]+)\s+(?P<name2>[a-z]+)', text)
r.groupdict()
```

[documentation here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html#re.match.groupdict)

Comment: Match only finds one match, not all matches.

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in method for doing this, but the expected result can be achieved by using list comprehensions.

```
[dict([[k, i if isinstance(i, str) else i[v-1]] for k,v in pat.groupindex.items()]) for i in pat.findall(text)]
```

With friendly formatting:

```
>>> [
...     dict([
...         [k, i if isinstance(i, str) else i[v-1]]
...         for k,v in pat.groupindex.items()
...     ])
...     for i in pat.findall(text)
... ]
```

We construct a list using a list comprehension, iterate over the result from `findall` which is either a list of strings or a list of tuples (0 or 1 capturing groups result in a list of `str`).

For each item in the result we construct a `dict` from another list comprehension which is generated from the `groupindex` field of the compiled pattern, which looks like:

```
>>> pat.groupindex
{'name2': 2, 'name': 1}
```

A list is constructed for each item in the `groupindex` and if the item from `findall` was a tuple, the group number from `groupindex` is used to find the correct item, otherwise the item is assigned to the (only extant) named group.

```
[k, i if isinstance(i, str) else i[v-1]]
```

Finally, a dict is constructed from the list of lists of strings.

Note that `groupindex` contains only named groups, so non-named capturing groups will be omitted from the resulting `dict`.

And the result:

```
[dict([[k, i if isinstance(i, str) else i[v-1]] for k,v in pat.groupindex.items()])  for i in pat.findall(text)]
[{'name2': 'sue', 'name': 'bob'}, {'name2': 'richard', 'name': 'jon'}]
```