# regex to dictionary using group label ?P<>

Tags: python, regex, label, regex-group

I'm using the regex module instead of default re module in python
https://code.google.com/p/mrab-regex-hg/wiki/GeneralDetails

I'm trying to do the following

```
>>> regex.compile('(?P<heavy>heavily|heavy)').search("My laptop is heavy or heavily").groupdict()
{'heavy': 'heavy'}
```

I expect it returns

```
{'heavy': ['heavy','heavily]}
```

regex.findall will match both heavy and heavily, but it doesn't work with group label

I have to solve it with regex, so iterative through string solutions are not acceptable.

Comment: Weird, I expected it to return `{'heavy': ['heavy','heavily']}` instead!

Comment: take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11103856/re-findall-which-returns-a-dict-of-named-capturing-groups

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Have you read the python documents on regexes?][1]

Relevant portion:

As the target string is scanned, REs separated by '|' are tried from left to right. When one pattern completely matches, that branch is accepted. This means that once A matches, B will not be tested further, even if it would produce a longer overall match.

This means that your regex:

```
(?P<heavy>heavily|heavy)
```

Will find the first matching string, which is "heavy", and save that string. It then says "congrats, I'm done!" and finishes scanning.

You need a regex that will capture both strings.
It then saves that string, `heavy`, into a group (as your regex requests) also called `heavy`. Your group dict command then returns this information. So you have a group named `heavy` with one regex match, also `heavy`, which gives you the return result of

```
{"heavy": "heavy"}
```

To resolve your issue, there are two solutions.

1. Use the regex findall method, which will return a list, and then you can turn this list into a dictionary. This is the easier route.
2. Craft a regex that will actually find both terms and place them into the same group. While doable, this is very convoluted.

I highly recommend you use the findall method instead, if you wish to search for multiple matches.