# Populate data from text files in CSV files by Python

Tags: python, pattern-matching, export-to-csv

I am trying to write a Python script which will parse data from text files by matching patterns.

My text file format looks like:

```
00 TOOLKIT     |   Cycles Run:  120001
...
01 TOOLKIT     | Efficiency: 28.1% of the time spent cycling.
...
06 TOOLKIT     !   Virtual: Max> 1082470400 bytes, Current>  640733184 bytes.
...
09 TOOLKIT     !   Actual: Max> 1082470800 bytes, Current>  640737981 bytes.
```

Now, we want to take `highest value of cycles`, `avg value of eff`, `max value of virtual_max` and `avg value of actual_current` and store it as a `21th row` in the CSV file.

The format of the CSV file should be like:

```
serial,cycles,eff,virtual_max,actual_current
1,120001,28.1,1082470400,640737981
...
20,120008,32.9,1082478900,648901992
21,120012,27.6,1082478900,644819986
```

Please let me know what would be the best method to:

> 1. Parse though the list of text files and pick up values from it one by one matching pattern.
> 2. Create a CSV file with Specific name and dump these values one by one for list of n e.g. 20 test files like this.
> 3. Apply max/mix/avg from the 20 rows of the CSV file and update the 21th row with the values.

It may sound like a 'do-my-homework' problem.
This is going to be my first Python script. 
Could not get much help over the net.

Comment: Where in your example file are you getting the serial from?

Comment: There are n number of text files. Each serial number signifies the same. e.g. there are 20 text files. Hence there will be 20 lines at first. The avg/min/max values are calculated and updated in row 21.

Comment: For parsing the lines of your text files that have multiple values, one option would be this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11103856/re-findall-which-returns-a-dict-of-named-capturing-groups