# How to return a list of dictionaries from the match of regex.findall?

Tags: python, regex, string, list, backend

I'm working on several hundreds of documents and I'm writing a function that will find specific words and its values and returns a list of dictionaries.

I'm looking specifically for a piece of specific information ('city' and the number that refers to it). However, in some documents, I have one city, and in others, I might have twenty or even one hundred, so I need something very generic.

A text example (the parenthesis are messed up like this):

```
text = 'The territory of modern Hungary was for centuries inhabited by a succession of peoples, including Celts, Romans, Germanic tribes, Huns, West Slavs and the Avars. The foundations of the Hungarian state was established in the late ninth century AD by the Hungarian grand prince Árpád following the conquest of the Carpathian Basin. According to previous census City: Budapest (population was: 1,590,316)Debrecen (population was: 115,399)Szeged (population was: 104,867)Miskolc (population was: 109,841). However etc etc'
```

or

```
text2 = 'About medium-sized cities such as City: Eger (population was: 32,352). However etc etc'
```

Using regex I found the string that I'm looking for:

```
p = regex.compile(r'(?<=City).(.*?)(?=However)')
m = p.findall(text)
```

Which returns the whole text as a list.

```
[' Budapest (population was: 1,590,316)Debrecen (population was: 115,399)Szeged (population was: 104,867)Miskolc (population was: 109,841). ']
```

Now, this is where I'm stuck and I don't know how to proceed. Should I use regex.findall or regex.finditer?

Considering that the amount of 'cities' varies in the documents, I would like to get a list of dictionaries back. If I run in text 2, I would get:

```
d = [{'cities': 'Eger', 'population': '32,352'}]
```

If I run in text one:

```
d = [{'cities': 'Szeged', 'population': '104,867'}, {'cities': 'Miskolc': 'population': 109,841'}]
```

I really appreciate any help, guys!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [re.findall which returns a dict of named capturing groups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11103856/re-findall-which-returns-a-dict-of-named-capturing-groups)

Answer (score 3):

You may use `re.finditer` with a regex having named capturing groups (named after your keys) on the matched text with `x.groupdict()` to get a dictionary of results:

```
import re
text = 'The territory of modern Hungary was for centuries inhabited by a succession of peoples, including Celts, Romans, Germanic tribes, Huns, West Slavs and the Avars. The foundations of the Hungarian state was established in the late ninth century AD by the Hungarian grand prince Árpád following the conquest of the Carpathian Basin. According to previous census City: Budapest (population was: 1,590,316)Debrecen (population was: 115,399)Szeged (population was: 104,867)Miskolc (population was: 109,841). However etc etc'
p = re.compile(r'City:\s*(.*?)However')
p2 = re.compile(r'(?P<city>\w+)\s*\([^()\d]*(?P<population>\d[\d,]*)')
m = p.search(text)
if m:
    print([x.groupdict() for x in p2.finditer(m.group(1))])

# => [{'population': '1,590,316', 'city': 'Budapest'}, {'population': '115,399', 'city': 'Debrecen'}, {'population': '104,867', 'city': 'Szeged'}, {'population': '109,841', 'city': 'Miskolc'}]
```

See the [Python 3 demo online](https://ideone.com/Mr03d3).

The second `p2` regex is

```
(?P<city>\w+)\s*\([^()\d]*(?P<population>\d[\d,]*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VX6Of4/1).

Here,

- `(?P<city>\w+)` - Group "city": 1+ word chars
- `\s*\(` - 0+ whitespaces and `(`
- `[^()\d]*` - any 0+ chars other than `(` and `)` and digits
- `(?P<population>\d[\d,]*)` - Group "population": a digit followed with 0+ digits or/and commas

You might try to run the `p2` regex on the whole original string (see [demo](https://ideone.com/8b5bCh)), but it may overmatch.

Comment: Hi Wiktor, thanks for the answer. One more thing, in the first group in p2 `(?P<city>\w+)` how do I deal white space between two names? e.g Novo Mesto. thank you again

Comment: @Dan Either `(?P<city>\w+(?:\s+\w+)*)\s*\([^()\d]*(?P<population>\d[\d,]*)` or `(?P<city>[^(]+?)\s*\([^()\d]*(?P<population>\d[\d,]*)`

Answer (score 0):

### A very good answer by @Wiktor. Since I spend some time on this, I am posting my answer.

```
d = [' Budapest (population was: 1,590,316)Debrecen (population was: 115,399)Szeged (population was: 104,867)Miskolc (population was: 109,841). ']
oo = []
import re
for i in d[0].split(")"):
    jj = re.search("[0-9,]+", i)
    kk, *xx = i.split()
    if jj:
        oo.append({"cities": kk , "population": jj.group()})
print (oo)

#Result--> [{'cities': 'Budapest', 'population': '1,590,316'}, {'cities': 'Debrecen', 'population': '115,399'}, {'cities': 'Szeged', 'population': '104,867'}, {'cities': 'Miskolc', 'population': '109,841'}]
```

Comment: Hi Akash, thank you for your answer. when I run your code I get an error '
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split''. Possibly because of the way I wrote the regex I think. do you know how can I fixed it? Thanks!

Comment: @Dan - 'split' works only for string object. I have used 'split' at two places to get split objects in a list. Suggestion: Just print the object before applying split. This will help you in finding the solution. Else share the exact data on which you are getting the error. I will try to check it.