# Regex to Capture rest of the line

Tags: regex

I have a regex that captures the following expression

`XPT 123A`

Now I need to add "something" to my regex to capture the remaining string as a group

`XPT 123A I AM VERY HAPPY`

So `XPT` would be group 1, `123A` group 2, and `I AM VERY HAPPY` group 3.

Here is my regex (also here http://regexr.com/4mocf):

`^([A-Z]{2,4}).((?=\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{0,4})`

EDIT:
I dont want to name my groups (editing b/c some people thought it was a dup of another question)

Comment: From your example I guess 1) only upper-case letters are used, and 2) second group always start with numbers and has no spaces, is this correct? If not you need to specify your requirements for each group.

Comment: `^([A-Z]{2,4}) (\d[a-zA-Z\d]{0,3})(?: (.*))?$`? Is Group 3 optional?

Comment: @m0skit0 yes, it is!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks! I can accept your answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [re.findall which returns a dict of named capturing groups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11103856/re-findall-which-returns-a-dict-of-named-capturing-groups)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming Group 3 is optional, you may use

```
^([A-Z]{2,4}) (\d[a-zA-Z\d]{0,3})(?: (.*))?$
^([A-Z]{2,4})\s+(\d[a-zA-Z\d]{0,3})(?:\s+(.*))?$
```

The `\s+` matches any 1+ whitespace chars.

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/a6G9Ud/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `([A-Z]{2,4})` - Group 1: two, three or four uppercase ASCII letters
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(\d[a-zA-Z\d]{0,3})` - Group 2: a digit followed with 0 or more alphanumeric chars
- `(?:\s+(.*))?` - an optional non-capturing group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of:

  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
  - `(.*)` - Group 3: any 0+ chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `$` - end of string

Comment: great explanation, tks!

Answer (score 2):

Just add the following suffix to your regex to capture the rest of the line:

```
(?<rest>.+)?$
```

Comment: Why so complicated? Why not just `(.*)$`?