# Using regex to extract information from string

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a regex in Python to extract some information from a string.

Given:

```
"Only in Api_git/Api/folder A: new.txt"
```

I would like to print:

```
Folder Path: Api_git/Api/folder A
Filename: new.txt
```

After having a look at some examples on the [re manual page](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html), I'm still a bit stuck.

This is what I've tried so far

```
m = re.match(r"(Only in ?P<folder_path>\w+:?P<filename>\w+)","Only in Api_git/Api/folder A: new.txt")

print m.group('folder_path')
print m.group('filename')
```

Can anybody point me in the right direction??

Comment: Is splitting by `:` possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the matched group from index 1 and 2 using capturing groups.

```
^Only in ([^:]*): (.*)$
```

Here is [demo](http://regex101.com/r/vV8uQ3/5)

sample code:

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'^Only in ([^:]*): (.*)$')
test_str = u"Only in Api_git/Api/folder A: new.txt"

re.findall(p, test_str)
```

---

If you want to print in the below format then try with substitution.

```
Folder Path: Api_git/Api/folder A 
Filename: new.txt
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/vV8uQ3/6)

sample code:

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'^Only in ([^:]*): (.*)$')
test_str = u"Only in Api_git/Api/folder A: new.txt"
subst = u"Folder Path: $1\nFilename: $2"

result = re.sub(p, subst, test_str)
```

Comment: Hey this looks good! Just a couple of questions, I think there's a typo because it only prints out "Folder Path: $1" at the moment.

Also, is there a quick way to save each value into its own variable eg.

`folder_path = test_str('folder_path')
filename = test_str('filename')`

Comment: get the matched groups from first example. I mentioned second example to print the desired output.

Comment: Read more [Capturing group with findall?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6018340/capturing-group-with-findall)

Comment: Nice detailed answer, +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern: `(Only in ?P<folder_path>\w+:?P<filename>\w+)` has a few flaws in it.

The `?P` construct is only valid as the first bit inside a parenthesized expression,
so we need this.

```
(Only in (?P<folder_path>\w+):(?P<filename>\w+))
```

The `\w` character class is only for letters and underscores. It won't match `/` or `.`, for example. We need to use a different character class that more closely aligns with requirements. In fact, we can just use `.`, the class of nearly all characters:

```
(Only in (?P<folder_path>.+):(?P<filename>.+))
```

The colon has a space after it in your example text. We need to match it:

```
(Only in (?P<folder_path>.+): (?P<filename>.+))
```

The outermost parentheses are not needed. They aren't wrong, just not needed:

```
Only in (?P<folder_path>.+): (?P<filename>.+)
```

It is often convenient to provide the regular expression separate from the call to the regular expression engine. This is easily accomplished by creating a new variable, for example:

```
regex = r'Only in (?P<folder_path>.+): (?P<filename>.+)'
... # several lines later
m = re.match(regex, "Only in Api_git/Api/folder A: new.txt")
```

The above is purely for the convenience of the programmer: it neither saves nor squanders time or memory space. There is, however, a technique that can save some of the time involved in regular expressions: **compiling**.

Consider this code segment:

```
regex = r'Only in (?P<folder_path>.+): (?P<filename>.+)'
for line in input_file:
    m = re.match(regex, line)
    ...
```

For each iteration of the loop, the regular expression engine must interpret the regular expression and apply it to the `line` variable. The `re` module allows us to separate the interpretation from the application; we can interpret once but apply several times:

```
regex = re.compile(r'Only in (?P<folder_path>.+): (?P<filename>.+)')
for line in input_file:
    m = re.match(regex, line)
    ...
```

Now, your original program should look like this:

```
regex = re.compile(r'Only in (?P<folder_path>.+): (?P<filename>.+)')
m = re.match(regex, "Only in Api_git/Api/folder A: new.txt")
print m.group('folder_path')
print m.group('filename')
```

However, I'm a fan of using comments to explain regular expressions. My version, including some general cleanup, looks like this:

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r'''(?x)                # Verbose
            Only\ in\             # Literal match
            (?P<folder_path>.+)   # match longest sequence of anything, and put in 'folder_path'
            :\                    # Literal match
            (?P<filename>.+)      # match longest sequence of anything and put in 'filename'
            ''')

with open('diff.out') as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
        m = re.match(regex, line)
        if m:
            print m.group('folder_path')
            print m.group('filename')
```

Comment: Is there a way to extract the regex from re.match()?

Comment: What do you mean by "*extract*"?

Comment: Sorry - I meant to define the regex outside of re.match("regex")

Comment: @Tomcelic - See my edit. In short, use `regex = re.compile(r'...'); re.match(regex, 'some text')`.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the limitation of the input, if this is the only input this will do the trick.

```
^Only in (?P<folder_path>[a-zA-Z_/ ]*): (?P<filename>[a-z]*.txt)$
```