# Findall vs search for overwriting groups in Python

Tags: python, regex

I found topic [Capturing group with findall?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6018340/capturing-group-with-findall) but unfortunately it is more basic and covers only groups that do not overwrite themselves.

Please let's take a look at the following example:

```
S = "abcabc"  # string used for all the cases below
```

## 1. Findall - no groups

`print re.findall(r"abc", S) # ['abc', 'abc']`

General idea: **No groups here so I expect `findall` to return a list of all matches** - please confirm.

In this case: `Findall` is looking for `abc`, finds it, returns it, then goes on and finds the second one.

## 2. Findall - one explicit group

`print re.findall(r"(abc)", S) # ['abc', 'abc']`

General idea: **Some groups here so I expect `findall` to return a list of all groups** - please confirm.

In this case: Why two results while there is only one group? I understand it this way:

- `findall` is looking for `abc`,
- finds it,
- places it in the group memory buffer,
- returns it,
- `findall` starts to look for `abc` again, and so on...

Is this reasoning correct?

## 3. Findall - overwriting groups

`print re.findall(r"(abc)+", S) # ['abc']`

This looks similar to the above yet returns only one `abc`. I understand it this way:

- `findall` is looking for `abc`,
- finds it,
- places it in the group memory buffer,
- **does not** return it because the RE itself demands to go on,
- finds another `abc`,
- places it in the group memory buffer (overwrites previous `abc`),
- string ends so searching ends as well.

Is this reasoning correct? I am very specific here so if there is anything wrong (even tiny detail) then please let me know.

## 4. Search - overwriting groups

`Search` scans through a string looking for a single match, so `re.search(r"(abc)", S)` and `re.search(r"(abc)", S)` rather obviously return only one `abc`, then let me get right to:

```
re.search(r"(abc)+", S)
print m.group()  # abcabc
print m.groups() # ('abc',)
```

a) Of course the whole match is `abcabc`, but we still have groups here, so can I conclude that groups are irrelevant (despite name) for `m.group()`? And that is why nothing gets overwritten for this method?

In fact, this grouping feature of parentheses is completely unnecessary here - in such cases I just want to use parentheses to stress what needs to be taken together when repeating things without creating any regex groups.

b) Can anyone explain a mechanism behind returning `abcabc` (in terms of buffers and so on) similarly like I did in bullet **3**?

Comment: Why not finish the previous question first? You have 2 answers there, and you have not provided any feedback.

Comment: I understand that you have some questions, that is fine. But in the way this site works, it is best to separate each question so that answers to the question can be complete, and not partial. A lot of what you are asking is also covered in the documentation of the regex module, and it's really hard to understand exactly what questions you are asking, i suggest you first do some research, perhaps your questions already have answers, otherwise, split your questions up, and give enough information for each one to be self-contained. Minimum working example of the code you want help with.

Comment: @Wiktor, my intention was to understand how groups work in Python first and then get back to the previous topic since I must admit that your and the other person's answers are not fully clear to me. I was wondering where to put my questions, but finally decided it is better to split them instead of making previous topic too long. Your answer just realized me that I need some initial knowledge to understand it and I asked about it here. If it is wrong I can put it there, but I cannot imagine how it could be more readable...

Comment: @Inbar, I am new on this site so every feedback is appreciated - thanks!
However, I don't know how could I put this long statement in the previous topic. Maybe I just wrongly referred to the previous topic here since these two subjects are truly separate. I will remove the beginning referring to it.

Comment: @Drizzt You just need to realize this is a Q&A site. Not a forum. Ask a question, get an answer. But you are asking many questions at once, that is not good for our format. Also the questions you are asking are not really best suited for this site. I suggest you do some research on your own about the documentation first, and also about how to use this site, and ask questions, there is a great [help] an [ask] guide.

Comment: @Inbar, regarding the research: of course I did it. Please note that I dedicated a lof of time to write this topic and believe me - I didn't do it if I had answers, but unfortunately I didn't find them either on this site or https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#regex-howto or https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html.

Comment: @Inbar, regarding many questions: well, I read http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/ and found that it could be valuable (for me and for others) to have this subject fully covered in one place. So I answered some of my own questions but left other to be confirmed by more experienced users so anyone interested in this topic could get thorough explanation in the future in this one topic. Maybe I was wrong.
Thanks for this link - I will read it and abide by the rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, let me state some facts:

- A **match value** (`match.group()`) is the (sub)text that meets the whole pattern defined in a regular expression. Matches can contain zero or more *capture groups*.
- A **capture value** (`match.group(1..n)`) is a part of the match (that can also be equal to the whole match if the whole pattern is enclosed into a capture group) that is matched with a parenthesized pattern part (a part of the pattern enclosed into a pair of unescaped parentheses).
- Some languages can provide access to the *capture collection*, i.e. all the values that were captured with a quantified capture group like `(\w{3})+`. In Python, it is possible with [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex), in .NET, with a CaptureCollection, etc.

> ## 1: No groups here so I expect `findall` to return a list of all matches - please confirm.

- True, only if there are capturing groups are defined in the pattern, `re.findall` returns a list of captured submatches. In case of `abc`, `re.findall` returns a list of matches.

> ## 2: Why two results while there is only one group?

- There are two matches, `re.findall(r"(abc)", S)` finds two matches in `abcabc`, and each match has one submatch, or captured substring, so the resulting array has 2 elements (`abc` and `abc`).

> ## 3: Is this reasoning correct?

- The `re.findall(r"(abc)+", S)` is looking for a match in the form `abcabcabc` and so on. It will match it as a whole and will keep the last `abc`  in the capture group 1 buffer. So, I think your reasoning is correct. *RE itself demands to go on* can be precised as *since the matching is not yet complete* (as there are still characters for the regex engine to test for a match).

> ## 4: the whole match is `abcabc`, but we still have groups here, so can I conclude that groups are irrelevant (despite name) for `m.group()`?

- No, the last group value is kept in this case. If you change your regex to `(\w{3})+` and the string to `abcedf` you will feel the difference as the output for that case will be `edf`. *And that is why nothing gets overwritten for this method?* - So, you are wrong, the preceding capture group value **is** overwritten with the following ones.

> ## 5: Can anyone explain a mechanism behind returning `abcabc` (in terms of buffers and so on) similarly like I did in bullet 3?

The `re.search(r"(abc)+", S)` will match `abcabc` (*match*, not *capture*) because

1. `abcabc` is searched for `abc` from left to right. RE finds `abc` at the start and tries to find another `abc` right from the location after the first `c`. RE puts the `abc` into Capture group buffer 1.
2. RE finds the 2nd `abc`, rewrites the capture group #1 buffer with it. Tries to find another `abc`.
3. No more `abc` is found  - return the matched value found : `abcabc`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, now it is almost fully clear to me. If I could ask you two more clarifying questions:

1) I asked *"Can I conclude that groups are irrelevant (despite name) for m.group()?"* and you answered *"no"*, but looking at your explanation of **5** where you stated that:

a) groups got overwritten which of course had impact on `m.groups()` method - `capture value`,

b) the whole match was still `abcabc` so I guess this overwriting had no impact on `m.group()` method - `match value`.
Then is the statement true that group overwriting is irrelevant for `m.group()` method?

Comment: 2) Regarding **2**, what do you mean by saying *"each match has one submatch, or captured substring"*? Did it mean that we have two matches `abc` and `abc`, and at the same time they make `(abc)` and `(abc)` captured groups? This was my understanding and in this bullet I wondered why the second captured group didn't overwrite the first one and I came to conclusion that the first group was returned by `findall` earlier. Is it true?

Comment: 1) I understand *group overwriting is irrelevant* that `group()` (=`group(0)`) as *group subvalue overwriting has not taken place*. No means it is wrong, overwriting takes place with any quantified capture group that matches subsequent adjacent substrings. 2) `r"(abc)"` pattern matches 2 consequent `abc` in `abcabc` (`abc` (1st match, 1 capture) + `abc` (2nd match, 1 capture). There is no quantified capture group here, thus, no "overwriting" occurs.

Comment: ad 1) Ok, I think we mean the same, I just don't know proper terms so I put it in different, less formal, way. Exactly like in the example you suggested: `re.search(r"(\w{3})+", "abcdef")`, overwriting takes place here so `groups()` returns `def`, but `group()`, without any number, still returns `abcdef` - as you explained when saying about `match value` - this is not affected by overwriting `abc` by `def`. Solved then.

Comment: ad 2) Hmmm, what do you mean by *"There is no quantified capture group here"*? So if you say there is no overwriting here, then do we have a separate buffer for each captured expression? In other words, do we have two groups here and first captured `abc` goes into the first group's buffer and second captured `abc` goes into the second group's buffer?

Comment: I see, and I agree Python `re` methods `m.group()` and `m.groups()` are a bit misleading. In .NET, it sounds less ambiguous: `match.Value` as opposed to `m.Groups`. As for the 2), again, Python naming is misleading.  No overwriting can take place with `r"(abc)"`, as the whole match `abc` is kept in the `m.group()` (=`m.group(0)`) and capture group text `abc` is stored in `m.group(1)`. Overwriting the capture group 1 would happen if a quantifier were present after `)`. **group()** is a **match value**, and **group(1)** is the first **capture group value**.

Comment: As a final check, could you please verify my understanding of what would be in your example?
`re.findall(r"(\w{3})", "abcdef")` returns `['abc', 'def']` - a list of captured submatches. To return this, `findall` scanned through the string and found two match objects (`m1` and `m2`). Match values are `m1.group() = 'abc'`, `m2.group() = 'def'` and captured submatches are `m1.group(1) = 'abc'`, `m2.group(1) = 'def'` so it gives us findall printing `[m1.group(1), m2.group(1)] = ['abc', 'def']`. Is it true? I really hope it is, otherwise I need to find a solid book and figure it out on my own.