# How to use {} in regex pattern with findall + Python

Tags: python, regex, findall

I'm creating a regex as below:

```
import re
asd = re.compile(r"(blah){2}")
mo = asd.search("blahblahblahblahblahblah ll2l 21HeHeHeHeHeHe lllo")
mo1 = asd.findall("blahblahblahblahblahblah")
print(mo.group())
print("findall output: ", mo1)
```

This returns output
    blahblah
    findall output:  ['blah', 'blah', 'blah']

**-Why findall output matches 'blah' three times, when its specified {2} times only in the pattern?**

If I change to {4}, then findall matches:

```
asd = re.compile(r"(blah){4}")
findall output:  ['blah']
```

**-How is {m} treated with re.search and re.findall ?**

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `blahblah`, `blahblah`, and `blahblah`. Three matches. Each one [captures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6018340/capturing-group-with-findall) `blah`.

Comment: I suppose you want to tell the regex engine too only return two values, right? Then, you do not need the limiting quantifier: get the results with re.findall and get the necessary items using their indices.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to *catch* the `(blah){2}` (the 2 `blah` you have there) you should wrap it:

```
asd = re.compile(r"((?:blah){2})")
```

> Note that I made sure not to catch the inside `blah` (using `?:`)

```
>>>asd = re.compile(r"((?:blah){2})")
>>>mo = asd.search("blahblahblahblahblahblah ll2l 21HeHeHeHeHeHe lllo")
>>>mo1 = asd.findall("blahblahblahblahblahblah")
>>>print(mo.group())
blahblah
>>>print("findall output: ", mo1)
findall output:  ['blahblah', 'blahblah', 'blahblah']
```

Exactly the same goes with the `{4}` you have there. The `regex` will find it, but will not catch it. if you want to catch it you should wrap it.

Answer (score 1):

`(blah){2}` captures and exhausts the string `blahblah` but only returns the *last* `blah` in `blahblah`. Since you have three `blahblah`s in your string, it will output `['blah', 'blah', 'blah']`

`(blah){4}` can only match once so it gives you `['blah']`