# Extracting numbers from a text file using regexp

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching

Iam trying to make a python script that reads a text file input.txt and then scans all phone numbers in that file and writes back all matching phone no's to output.txt

lets say text file is like:

> Hey my number is 1234567890 and another number is +91-1234567890. but if none of these is available you can call me on +91 5645454545 (or) mail me at abc@xyz.com

it should match **1234567890**, **+91-1234567890** and **+91 5645454545**

```
import re

no = '^(\+[1-9]\d{0,2}[- ]?)?[1-9][0-9]{9}' #i think problem is here
f2 = open('output.txt','w+')

for line in open('input.txt'):
    out = re.findall(no,line)
    for i in out : 
        f2.write(i + '\n')
```

Regexp for no is like : it takes country codes upto 3 digits and then a - or space which is optional and country code itself is optional and then a 10 digit number.

Comment: output file doesn't show the expected. it just shows +91- and +91 . so i gues s there is problem in writing regexp. How adding (.*?) in beginning will change behaviour of regexp ?

Comment: so you want only  phone numbers in output file or you want to remove duplicates as well

Comment: No i dont want to remove duplicates. i want that after running script on above give text it should write 1234567890, +91-1234567890 and +91 5645454545 to output.txt but after running script it just writes +91- and +91

Comment: use this regex: '(?:\+[1-9]\d{0,2}[- ]?)?[1-9][0-9]{9}'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the problem is with your regex. Fortunately, it's a small one. You just need to remove the `^` character:

```
'(\+[1-9]\d{0,2}[- ]?)?[1-9]\d{9}'
```

The `^` signifies that you want to match only at the beginning of the string. You want to match multiple times throughout the string. Here's a [`101demo`](https://regex101.com/r/w81IwB/2).

---

For python, you'll need to specify a non-capturing group as well with `?:`. Otherwise, [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) does not return the complete match:

> Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of
>   strings. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned
>   in the order found. **If one or more groups are present in the pattern,
>   return a list of groups.**

Bold emphasis mine. Here's a [relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6018340/capturing-group-with-findall).

This is what you get when you specify non-capturing groups for your problem:

```
In [485]: re.findall('(?:\+[1-9]\d{0,2}[- ]?)?[1-9]\d{9}', text)
Out[485]: ['1234567890', '+91-1234567890', '+91 5645454545']
```

Comment: it works rightly in regex101 but it just writes +91- and +91 to my output.txt .  Please see my complete code

Comment: Thanks man ! it worked. i have spent a lot of time over it. can you please elabore about [ need to specify a non-capturing group as well with ?:]

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to upvote. Thanks for answer

Comment: @mcjoshi Are you sure? ;p

Comment: Hehe.. Thanks for everything :)

Answer (score 2):

you can use

```
(?:\+[1-9]\d{1,2}-?)?\s?[1-9][0-9]{9}
```

see the demo at [demo](https://regex101.com/r/VkOkP9/3)

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: See my code in question. I want to say it just writes +91 and +91- to output.txt

Comment: For python, you'll need to specify a non-capturing group as well with ?:. Otherwise, re.findall does not return the complete match: see the updated answer and demo

Answer (score 2):

this code will work:

```
import re

no = '(?:\+[1-9]\d{0,2}[- ]?)?[1-9][0-9]{9}' #i think problem is here
f2 = open('output.txt','w+')

for line in open('input.txt'):
    out = re.findall(no,line)
    for i in out :
        f2.write(i + '\n')
```

The output will be:

```
1234567890
+91-1234567890
+91 5645454545
```

Comment: yeah it works :) i need to ask one more thing :: suppose my input text file contains many newlines between two paragraphs. How do i remove extra newlines using regexps?

Comment: can you give a sample for your problem?

Answer (score -1):

```
pattern = '\d{10}|\+\d{2}[- ]+\d{10}'

matches = re.findall(pattern,text)

o/p -> ['1234567890', '+91-1234567890', '+91 5645454545']
```