# python regex match content crossing multiple lines

Tags: python, regex

I have a txt file, include multiple line.My result crossing multiple lines.

for example, my data can be simplified as the following:

***target_str*** =

```
x:-2.12343234
aaa:-3.05594480202
aaa:-3.01292995004
aaa:-2.383299
456:-2.232342
x:-2.53739230
aaa:-2.96875038099
aaa:-2.92326261448
aaa:-2.87628054847
bbb:-2.82755928961
456:-2.77678240323
x:-2.3433210
aaa:-2.72356707049
aaa:-2.6675072938
aaa:-2.60827106148
456:-2.3323232
x:-2.8743920
aaa:-2.433233
aaa:-2.9747893
aaa:-2.9747893
bbb:-2.43873
456:-2.43434
```

I want to match

```
x:.....
aaa:.....
aaa:.....
aaa:.....
bbb:.....
456:.....
```

means if there exist bbb, then I pick up the lines from x:... to 456:....

The expected results for the example data is:

```
x:-2.53739230
aaa:-2.96875038099
aaa:-2.92326261448
aaa:-2.87628054847
bbb:-2.82755928961
456:-2.77678240323

x:-2.8743920
aaa:-2.433233
aaa:-2.9747893
aaa:-2.9747893
bbb:-2.43873
456:-2.43434
```

I write:

```
a=re.findall(r"x:(.*\n){4}bbb:.*\n456.*",target_str)

print(a)
```

But the results is:

```
['aaa:-2.87628054847\n', 'aaa:-2.9747893\n']
```

This is not correct, can anyone help me? thanks a lot.

Comment: `re.findall` returns the captured group. Turn the capturing group in a non capturing group, `x:(?:.*\n){4}bbb:.*\n456.*`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capturing group with findall?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6018340/capturing-group-with-findall)

Comment: Just a tip: There are some [neat tools](https://regex101.com/) that help you write correct regex.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness thanks ,this results solved my question. great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with following regex:

```
(x:(?:.*\n){4}bbb:.*\n456.*)
```

`(?:.*\n)` - `?:` Makes group non capturing, so it won't be set to output.

Adding parenthesses on whole regex makes it an group which you would like to see as output

Comment: The parentheses are redundant by the way, you don't *need* to capture the match.