# Python regex findall() returns unwanted substrings (including the correct answer)

Tags: python, regex

I have to write a python function which gets a line of code as an input and returns true if that line contains ternary operator (and counts them!), else false. I wrote a few version of regex which worked perfectly on this site https://regexr.com/, but for example on Google Colab neither of them worked.

```py
def ternaryOp(line):
  found_operator=re.findall(r'(((=|==|<|>|<=|>=|!=)[\s\t]*)?[\s\t]*.+[\s\t]*\?[\s\t]*((.+:.*)|(.*:.+)))',line)
  if found_operator:
      print(len(found_operator))
      print(found_operator)
      return True
  else:
    return False


ternaryOp('category=age<18?child:adult')
```

Expected result:

```
1
[('category=age<18?child:adult')]
True
```

Actual result:

```
6
[('category=age<18?child:adult', '', '', 'child:adult', 'child:adult', '')]
True
```

Comment: You are doing a lot of extra capturing that you don't need.  Try this `found_operator=re.findall(r'((?:(?:=|==|<|>|<=|>=|!=)[\s\t]*)?[\s\t]*.+[\s\t]*\?[\s\t]*(?:.*?:.*)+)',line)`

Comment: Why do you say the Python result is incorrect? Perhaps it isn't what you _wanted_, but that's not the same as _incorrect_.  How did you create that regex?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capturing group with findall?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6018340/capturing-group-with-findall)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found the solution which works for me. Thank you all!

```
re.findall(r'(?:(?:=|==|<|>|<=|>=|!=)?[\s\t]*[\s\t]*[^?:]+[\s\t]*\?[\s\t]*(?:.*?:[^ ]*))')
```

Answer (score 0):

It's doing [exactly what it's supposed and documented to do](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall):

> If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group. Empty matches are included in the result.

Your regex has 6 capture groups, therefore each match is a 6-tuple, with each element of the tuple being a capture group. Either work with that, or use non-capturing groups (`(?:pattern)`) for groups you don't specifically care about, or use `re.finditer` which yields *match objects* and thus much richer and more flexible results.

Incidentally you're working very inefficiently, if you just want to know that a pattern can be found in a string use `re.match` or `re.search`, the code you're posting here has no need for the capabilities of `findall` since you're just checking whether it found anything.

Comment: Actually I have to count them. The above version just returns true/false. But if there are more than one ternary operators in a line the other functions won't work.

Comment: Fair enough then.