# How do I use findall in html string?

Tags: python, html

**My code:**

```py
mug_cup_link = '.....'
mc_source = urlopen(mug_cup_link).read()
name=findall('<a href="" >".*"</a>',mc_source)
```

I am searching for multiple names, not just a single one.

Comment: Tip: Don't use regex to parse HTML. Use some parser instead. See [Parsing HTML Using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709079/parsing-html-using-python).

Comment: but my assessment must use regex . I can't change it . And I have no idea how to locate the item name

Comment: You should use capturing groups. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6018340/capturing-group-with-findall).

Comment: Also, [regex101](https://regex101.com) may be useful for you.

Comment: thank:D  it is really useful

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use regular expressions you to change you re this way

```
import re
s = """<a href="https://zombieunlimited.com/rancid-santa-mug/" >Rancid Santa Mug</a> """
print(re.search('<a.*>(.*)<\/a>', s).start(1))
```

Hope it works for you!