# Regex to match number among hex and complex characters

Tags: python, regex

I have a text in quote:

```
"Ngo&#-225;n:   8.40   Zữ kăn:   6.5   Kịch zuử:   0.0   Đoan l"&#-237;;:   5   GTBH:   6.50   KH: 6"
```

I want to extract all number after `:` like this in Python by using regex:

```
"8.40           6.5         0.0        5           6.50            6"
```

Could you show me how to do with this task? Thanks.

I just update what I've done:

```py
(?<!\:)\d{1,2}\.?\d*?
```

Using `Ngo&#-225;n:   8.40   Zữ kăn:   6.5   Kịch zuử:   0.0   Đoan l"&#-237;;:   5   GTBH:   6.50   KH: 6` as test string. See  [demo here](https://pythex.org/?regex=(%3F%3C!%5C%3A)%5Cd%7B1%2C2%7D%5C.%3F%5Cd*%3F&test_string=Ngo%26%23-225%3Bn%3A%20%20%208.40%20%20%20Z%E1%BB%AF%20k%C4%83n%3A%20%20%206.5%20%20%20K%E1%BB%8Bch%20zu%E1%BB%AD%3A%20%20%200.0%20%20%20%C4%90oan%20l%22%26%23-237%3B%3B%3A%20%20%205%20%20%20GTBH%3A%20%20%206.50%20%20%20KH%3A%206&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0).

Sill, this pattern captures hex values:  `225` and `237`. Can we modify something to extract these?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `re.findall` with the following regex.

```
:\s*([\d\.]+)
```

I also test result on Python.

```
import re

string = "Ngo&#-225;n: 8.40 Zữ kăn: 6.5 Kịch zuử: 0.0 Đoan l\"&#-237;;: 5 GTBH: 6.50 KH: 6"

regex = re.compile(r":\s*([\d\.]+)")
result = regex.findall(string)
print(result)
```

Result.

```
['8.40', '6.5', '0.0', '5', '6.50', '6']
```

Comment: Perfect ! One thing could you explain a bit is that when I test your suggested pattern ":\s*([\d\.]+) " online. The result still keeps colons ":" but when I run with re.compile and re.findall, the result is perfect?

Comment: When we use `findall` with capturing group. The function `findall` just returns the captured groups.

Comment: You could read this article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6018340/capturing-group-with-findall

Answer (score 1):

The pattern `(?<!\:)\d{1,2}\.?\d*?` that you tried starts the match with a digit, asserting what is directly to the left is not `:` which in the example data is true for all numbers.

As there are 1 or more spaces after the colon, you could use a capturing group instead of a lookbehind:

```
:[^\S\r\n]+(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

**Explanation**

- `:` Match literally
- `[^\S\r\n]+` Match 1+ whitespace chars without a newline
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` Match 1+ digits with an optional decimal part
- `)` Close group 1

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8EZGV6/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/VW7CLb)

---

Using the [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/), and if the whitspace chars can be optional,  you can also assert `:` at the left followed by 0+ whitespace chars before matching the number:

```
(?<=:\s*)\d+(?:\.\d+)?
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6m7Cca/1) | [Python demo](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEoNT21gourILGkJLUoT8FWoUhJw97G1iqmWEszJkVbw94qRg9Ia9orcRUDZTWUYpT80vPVlHWNjEyt86wUFBQs9EwMgFTUw93rFbKPNIPFzPRMgaT3w93dyRkKVaUPd68FiRrogRQemZCfmKeQE6MEMsTY3NoaJAVS7h7i5AHVDFLnDeSYxSjF5ClpchUUZeaVaIDdqpeWmZeSmJOjAXWyjkKxpub//wA)

---

Perhaps as an alternative, to get the desired numbers from the example data, instead of checking for a `:` at the left, you can also assert no `;` directly at the right:

```
\d+(?:\.\d+)?\b(?!;)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZZZWue/1)

Comment: Thanks The fourth bird ! Your answer is perfect too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`re.findall(":\\s*([0-9.]+)",s)`